# Is criminalisation the right word to describe the involvement of criminals?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, subcontinental-english, politics

In the Indian media and public discourse, the phrase 'criminalisation of politics' is often used to indicate one or more of the following:

1. The nexus between organized crime and politics
2. High, and still increasing numbers of politicians with criminal cases pending against them.
3. Corrupt practices committed by politicians.

Apparently, the third form of usage isn't unique to India, as [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criminalization_of_politics) talks about the United States.

[OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/criminalization) says that criminalisation is "The action of turning an activity into a criminal offence by making it illegal." Clearly, by this definition, politics has not been criminalised in India. Criminalisation of politics could be said to have taken place in countries where formation or membership of political parties is illegal.

Countries with strict drug laws could have been said to have criminalised drugs, jurisdiction with strict laws on firearms usage and possession could have been said to have criminalised firearms, while those places with restrictive business laws could be said (not literally) to have criminalised business.

I request people to check if my understanding of the word criminalisation is correct, and that the Indian media uses it incorrectly. If that is the case, what would be correct and succinct words or phrases which mean (1), (2), and (3) in the first paragraph.

Comment: criminalization describes a process occurring in a  particular area of life. Here: politics

Comment: If it's already illegal there's no need to make it illegal (by passing laws against it) in order for it to be considered criminal. Criminalization in this context means that politics is being criminalized *by the* **illegal activities** *going on within it* (not by any laws having to be passed to make it so). It's the illegal activities which are making politics criminal -- not any change in laws.

Comment: @Bread I understand that. But is the usage correct? I can find no dictionary definition which contains this meaning. 

Is such usage common in the English speaking world?

Comment: @Lambie - I'd be glad of a dictionary reference, where the word is defined in this way.

Comment: Sorry, but the suffix "zation" in English is what it is. It's like alphabetization or politicization.

Comment: In other words, no dictionary reference?

Comment: @ranban282 the words **criminalize** and **criminalization** are not listed at all in my dictionary (Webster's c.1959). But of course criminal is. And so are the suffixes, **ize** and **ization**, which may be utilized to modify the meaning of *criminal*. So, my advice is to study the meanings of the word criminal, along with the meanings of both suffixes commonly used to transform the noun into verbs. Your examples are from common speech, not legal speech. So the meaning should be fairly forthright.

Comment: @Bread If I were to say criminalisation of marijuna, it would mean that the possession or use of the substance has been made illegal, and may have penalties. This question has actually been triggered by an article I once read in The Economist, which talked about 'criminalisation of business'. I was used to the 'Indian' sense, but was surprised to learn that it talked of excessive regulation. 
The author of the answer has quoted an NYT article, in which the word has been used similar to marijuna or business. So are both senses correct? Or only one? If so, which one?

Comment: @ranban282 It is obvious to me that either verbal meaning is correct, and that it all depends on context.

Comment: One cannot 'criminalise' politics or business. Politics and business are legitimate occupations, personally and corporately. One can criminalise the sale of harmful drugs. Then it becomes a criminal activity. But certain _persons_ involved in legitimate activities can 'behave criminally' within their own sphere of activity. But they have not 'criminalised' the entire sphere through their individual behaviour. It remains untainted - available for anyone else to use the arena properly and lawfully.

Comment: Thanks Nigel, this is consistent with my understanding, but others seem to disagree.

Comment: "Politics and business are legitimate occupations" is a highly subjective judgment call, not to  mention an extreme generalization. Anything can become tainted with corruption / criminal activity.

Comment: Take marriage for example, which is a sacrament. Adultery and other infractions can cause a marriage to be annulled -- or to be less than holy, in any case. Ideals are not untouchable. They are subject to corruption. Example: some people get married for reasons that are less than honorable.

Comment: @Bread While what you may have said in your last comments may be true, they don't address the original question, and deviate form the topic significantly.  I do understand from an earlier comment, that, according to you, both usages are acceptable, and the meaning depends on the context. Fair enough, makes sense.  I'd like to hear what other  experts have to say on this, though.

Comment: @ranban282 My point is that "politics and business are legitimate occupations" is not a true statement. And perhaps this question would be better answered on the Philosophy SE, after all.

Comment: @Bread My original question was certainly about usage, and not philosophy,  it seems that you are giving it a more philosophical tone with your comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76382/discussion-between-bread-and-ranban282).

Answer (score 1):

"Criminalization describes a process occurring in a particular area of life. Here: politics." (attribute - an esteemed member of this site)

"Criminalization of politics" is a political buzzword in the United States used in the media, by commentators, bloggers as well as high-ranking government officials in any party who have been indicted, faced criminal or ethical investigations or have been suspected of criminal activity, primarily to gain and/or maintain office.  Your [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criminalization_of_politics) reference is highly partisan.

Criminalization of politics does not imply organized crime involvement though I am sure there is some. And known criminals are barred. Politicians do though det convicted during and after office.  It is typically used to cripple or impede a politician or politicians in their governance.  In this democracy one politician's meat may be another's poison! So YES (with all said) to your question, with nuance and context.

Here is a recent NY Times article on same:  [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/11/28/opinion/politics-investigations-trump-russia.html)

Comment: suggested edits appreciated

Comment: Thanks for the NYT article, it is a de-facto English standard. The NYT has the word criminalization correctly, and is consistent with the OED definition.  The sense used in the Wikipedia article is completely different. My question is if that sense, along with other senses mentioned in the original question is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot 'criminalise' politics or business. Politics and business are legitimate occupations, personally and corporately. One can criminalise the sale of harmful drugs. Then it becomes a criminal activity.

Certain persons involved in legitimate activities can 'behave criminally' within their own sphere of activity. But they have not 'criminalised' the entire sphere through their individual behaviour. It remains untainted - available for anyone else to use the arena properly and lawfully.

> **Criminalise** : 2. trans. To turn (**an activity**) into a criminal offence **by making it illegal**.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/271579?redirectedFrom=criminalise#eid)

---

It would be correct and appropriate to say that in a certain locality, at a certain time, that a **certain organisation** had **become corrupted** by the activities of certain individuals such that everyone involved in that organisation could not function without partaking of the corruption. Then, the only valid and ethical action would be to resign from that organisation.

But I would say that the organisation would have to be named. And it is an organisation of which one must actively be a member. 'Politics' and 'business' are not organisations - they are open spheres of activity which require no 'membership' as such.

> **Corrupt** 3. To render morally unsound or ‘rotten’; to destroy the moral purity or chastity of; to pervert or ruin (a good quality); to debase, defile.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/42035?rskey=cavAZQ&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

Comment: This answer is consistent with the OED definition. 

However, while one cannot literally criminalize politics or business, but there's the NYT article talking about criminalising political differences. And the Economist article talked of 'criminalising' business by making the business environment, regulation, and laws ridiculously difficult to comply with.  (This happened in India, in the 1970s)

In a dictatorship, or in any state where political activity is restricted,  politics can indeed be said to have been criminalised, I think.

Comment: @ranban282 I have added more in order to answer the second part of your question.

Comment: @ranban282 In that case (regarding the NYT allegations) it is being asserted that the Government - as such - is so corrupted that nobody can function within it without participating in the corruption. But still, it is not true that 'politics' as such, inherently, has become 'criminalised'.

Comment: Did we read the same NYT article? The article talks about corruption initally, but that is not the thrust of the piece.  The word  criminalization is  used thrice -  twice in the body, and once at the end, as a part of the book title, and its past participle criminalized in the title. 

It is used in a manner consistent with OED, and not corruption, or involvement with criminals. It talks about over-zealous prosecution of legitimate political decisions, and John Adams imprisoning political opponents.

Comment: @Nigel J ~ how can anyone say that politics is not criminal inherently. **the activities associated with the governance of a country or other area, especially the debate or conflict among individuals or parties having or hoping to achieve power.** does not preclude criminal activity.

Comment: @Bread A country must be governed in some way. And it should be done in a 'sensible and judicious' manner, as is the meaning of 'politic'.

Comment: @Nigel J ~ but we're discussing meaning (i.e. reality, truth), not ideals. Politics is corruptible. Anything is corruptible. And that's what "criminalization" **means**. Unless, you want to get all legalistic about it. But the OP never mentioned legal terminology (which belongs on the Law SE, anyway). It only referred to common usage of the word. Criminal (noun) + **ize** = verb, "make criminal". Criminalize (noun) + ization = verb "the making of criminals". It surely can apply to politics, as with nearly anything else, imho.

Comment: @Bread You are misusing the word 'criminalise'. It just does not mean what you are trying to make it mean. An organisation of particular individuals can be _corrupted_ such that it cannot function legitimately.   But that is not what 'criminalise' means.

Comment: @Nigel J ~ **The action of turning an activity into a criminal offence by making it illegal.** You're assuming that can only happen through changes in law, which would make it legal terminology. But the OP asked about common usage. If the laws already exist, one only needs to break those laws, in order to criminalize anything.

Comment: @Bread Are you therefore saying that all politics and all business, globally have been 'criminalised' as a permanence ? ?

Comment: @Nigel J ~ The root word, **crime** is highly subjective: mid-13c., "sinfulness," from Old French crimne (12c., Modern French crime), from Latin crimen (genitive criminis) "charge, indictment, accusation; crime, fault, offense," perhaps from cernere "to decide, to sift" (from PIE root *krei- "to sieve," thus "discriminate, distinguish"). (Etymonline). Wherefore, if you want to make it a legal term, it needs to be addressed on the Law SE, Philosophy SE, Politics SE, or elsewhere. Politics is not above the law.  Example: there are States whose laws would be illegal anywhere else in the world.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76385/discussion-between-bread-and-nigel-j).

Comment: @Bread Thank you but no. My answer stands and I have other things to do. Regards.